# res.send is not sending data to fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using fetch api on my client:

```
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/buy", {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: JSON.stringify({value:input.value}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
     .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

and on my server side i have:

```
app.post('/buy' , ( req , res ) => {
    res.send({status:200,redirect:'asd'});
})
```

However client code isnt recieving any data, did i overlook something or why is this happenin?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'd use `res.json` ... Have you tried pinging your server using curl or postman (to isolate wether the problem lies on the client or serverside)

Comment: Do you have indication that your `/buy` endpoint is being reached? Is anything being sent back, if even an error?

Comment: it is reached,i put console.log and it printed it out

Comment: Yes try with postman.  It will show you an error at least.  Try to `res.send('abcd')` to check if this will received from client side.

Comment: Inside your then(), write `console.log(res)` to see if you getting the requested data

Comment: it returns data in postman but console.log doesnt print anything

Answer (score 0):

You do the following:

```
res.status(200).json({status:200,redirect:'asd'});
```

As far as I know, res.send sends a string, while res.json sends JSON

Try a little change on client side

```
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response))
```

You use JSON.stringify when processing response in your code, but actually you need to do the reverse - JSON.parse. In your code it's done already in the form of res.json(); So you need just to toss away stringify command.

I just tested the code above on my machine, everything works fine. Server returns response.

Comment: still nothing is recieved on client side

Comment: i tried your edited code and it still does not do anything

Comment: Then unfortunately the problem is outside of the code that you showed. I would advise you to look in devtools in chrome, network tab. When you send request you will see it, as well as response to it. Post server reply here so that we can see.

Comment: thats the problem, i do not see anything in the newtwork tab, there is no post request

Comment: share your client-side code, what the page does, how it looks

Comment: the code i posted is literally everything, except i am binding the code to onclick

Comment: well ok, take next steps. Console.log data inside fetch before sending post request, console.log data server-side (req.body). This way you understand that data was sent and received. This is all you need to do. If inside fetch console.log is empty, that means POST is not done client side. If inside app.post req.body will be empty, that means problem is server side.

Comment: when i do post via postman, i recieve data, data is being send and recieved on server

Answer (score 0):

Try without the JSON.stringify